# Why does my data return blank pdf when I run it?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, reportlab

I have  two csv files which I converted to pdf, one returns the correct results while the other returns blank. I can't tell why this is so.
This is the code I wrote.

```
df = pd.read_csv('cards.csv')
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns={"index": ""})
data = [df.columns.to_list()] + df.values.tolist()
table = Table(data)
table.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black)
]))
story = [Paragraph("My Report", getSampleStyleSheet()['Heading1']),Spacer(1, 20),table]
c = Canvas('resulted.pdf')
f = Frame(inch, inch, 6 * inch, 9 * inch)
f.addFromList(story,c)
c.save()
```

This is the data structure

[image: Data structure]